# How to use ES2020 features in a Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ecmascript-2020

I've been trying to use ES2020 features like optional chaining feature in next.js but it needs to a new loader,
how do I fix this?

Comment: React itself doesn't care about your ES features. What are you using to transpile and package your app?

Comment: @AKX I use babel

Comment: Did you try to [update react-scripts](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add this plugin in devDependencies in package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
    }
```

then run this command

```
npm install
```

Comment: rather run `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` and let `npm` control your version ;)

Comment: @bbortt For each new feature of ES2020, I have to install a plugin?

Comment: it's exactly the same behaviour as you mentioned in your answer, but you should never "manually" controll the version (editting `package.json`).

Comment: @bbortt Tanks a lot